# How to place multiple bar in jqplot bar chart

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have bar chart which is done using jqplot now i want to have 3 bars on the each point of the x axis. How can it be done.? please check this image  http://peltiertech.com/Utility/pix/clusterstackchart.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chat3" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 4];
var s3 = [14, 9, 3, 8];
plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2, s3], {
    // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
stackSeries: true,
captureRightClick: true,
seriesDefaults:{
renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
rendererOptions: {
          // Put a 30 pixel margin between bars.
barMargin: 30,
          // Highlight bars when mouse button pressed.
          // Disables default highlighting on mouse over.
highlightMouseDown: true   
},
pointLabels: {show: true}
},
axes: {
xaxis: {
renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
},
yaxis: {
padMin: 0
}
},
legend: {
show: true,
location: 'e',
placement: 'outside'
}     
});
  // Bind a listener to the "jqplotDataClick" event.  Here, simply change
  // the text of the info3 element to show what series and ponit were
  // clicked along with the data for that point.
$('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick',
function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
$('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
}
);
});


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have that solution.but can provide after few hours

Comment: okay but asap...using the above code it just gives one bar at one point in x axis..i need 3 bars on one point of x axis...check my image link bro.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270945/jqplot-side-by-side-stacked-bar-chart

Comment: you cannot call this one as duplicate where that issue was not solved..so even i came across the same problem, i checked that link but saw that no one solved his issue. so i had to raise my doubt.

Comment: I've just answered the original question, although you may find the answer disappointing. Your duplicate question should be closed by a trusted user.

Comment: You mean its not possible in jqplot? but check this link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jqplot-users/XIeLzEHMpwc

Comment: no, i am still struggling with that, I am not able to get more than one bar on one point of x axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                    var s1 = [ 1, 2, 2, 3 ];
                    var s2 = [ 12, 32, 3, 12 ];
                    var s3 = [ 12, 32, 54, 64 ];
                    var ticks = [ 'Section1', 'section2', 'section3',
                            'section4' ];

                    plot2 = $.jqplot('chart3', [ s1, s2, s3 ], {
                        animate : !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
                        seriesDefaults : {
                            renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                            pointLabels : {
                                show : true
                            },
                            rendererOptions : {
                                barPadding : 8, // number of pixels between
                                // adjacent bars in the same
                                // group (same category or bin).
                                barMargin : 25, // number of pixels between
                                // adjacent groups of bars.
                                barDirection : 'vertical', // vertical or
                                // horizontal.
                                barWidth : 20, // width of the bars. null to
                            // calculate automatically.

                            }
                        },
                        series : [ {
                            label : 'X axis 1'
                        }, {
                            label : 'X axis 2'
                        }, {
                            label : 'X axis 3'
                        }, ],
                        seriesColors : [ "#efa229", "#245779", "#4BB2C5" ],
                        axesDefaults : {
                            base : 10, // the logarithmic base.
                            tickDistribution : 'even', // 'even' or 'power'.
                        // 'even' will produce
                        // with even visiual
                        // (pixel)
                        // spacing on the axis. 'power' will produce ticks
                        // spaced by
                        // increasing powers of the log base.
                        },
                        axesDefaults : {
                            tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                            tickOptions : {

                                fontSize : '7pt'
                            }
                        },
                        axes : {
                            xaxis : {
                                renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                                ticks : ticks
                            },
                            yaxis : {
                                // Don't pad out the bottom of the data range.
                                // By default,
                                // axes scaled as if data extended 10% above and
                                // below the
                                // actual range to prevent data points right on
                                // grid boundaries.
                                // Don't want to do that here.
                                padMin : 0
                            }
                        },
                        tickOptions : {

                            fontSize : '7pt'
                        },
                        legend : {
                            show : true,
                            location : 'ne', // compass direction, nw, n, ne,
                            // e, se, s, sw, w.
                            xoffset : 12, // pixel offset of the legend box
                            // from the x (or x2) axis.
                            yoffset : 12, // pixel offset of the legend box
                            // from the y (or y2) axis.
                            placement : 'outside'
                        },
                        cursor : {
                            show : false,

                            showTooltip : true,
                            tooltipLocation : 'ne',

                        },
                        grid : {
                            background : 'white'
                        }
                    });
```

above is the code that i have implemented for showing 3 bar in the each x point..hope you find this helpfull

following is the helpfull js and css file

```
jquery.jqplot.min.css"
```

```
jquery.jqplot.min.js
jqplot.highlighter.min.js
jqplot.barRenderer.min.js
jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js
jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
jqplot.cursor.min.js
jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js
jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js
jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js
```

Comment: wait bro..let me use it and let you know..thanks anyway..its one hope

Comment: and one doubt. which js file i should import to my html file?

Comment: please let me know if u want it another way e.g. i just misunderstand the image and gave another chart query in which every x point have 3 individual bars

Comment: i have implemented a long time ago and right now i just have found this few line code in that..so i cant tell u sure which js file.but rather include all bar chart js for now as a testing purpose and also include categoryaxesrender js.(not sure about name)

Comment: okay mate surely let u know..but be here for sometime..so i could ask you some doubts if i get while doing that :)

Comment: hey at the end of your code you have mentioned chart2 as well as chat3, from where that chat3 has come bro?

Comment: Don't use that line of code..sorry i have just put wrong code at the end...just ignore that line of code with chart 2..and please don't just copy paste the code..understand the code and then try to implement with your scenario.otherwise it will give error

Comment: jquery.js, jquery.min.js, jquery.jqplot.js,jquery.jqplot.js, jqplot.barRenderer.min.js, jqplot.barRenderer.js, jqplot.barRenderer.js, jqplot.barRenderer.js, jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js, jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js, jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js, jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js, jqplot.pointLabels.js.  these are js files i included but still didnt get output bro

Comment: shall i directly copy and paste it to my html page friend or is there any error?

Comment: first try to include the js and css that i updated in my answer//its working for me..and please as i told u before dont just copy paste..try to understand the things in code

Comment: can u please do one thing...just put this line at the end $('#chart3').bind('jqplotDataClick',
function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
$('#info3').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
}
);
});

Comment: I just copy pasted the same but nothing is displaying yar.. :(

Comment: and how to check the error in eclipse i used ctrl+shift+j..nothing happens

Comment: jst try with your code..replace your code with my code dont copy paste..and let me know what error coming.in browser i told u to do with ctrl+shift+j .i dont know about eclipse

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: i am new to this jquery so feeling difficulty..:( by the way can you show me the image of your chart?

Comment: please check about any brackets or semicolon u left out.there must be a syntax error..

Comment: by the way friend can you show me the type of chart you are getting? is it look like this?  http://peltiertech.com/Utility/pix/clusterstackchart.png because i want it to be cluster stacked bar chart

Comment: with this chart code you can have only single coloured of multiple bar at each x points..

Comment: wat dude, i have been telling that i need to have multiple bar at each point of x axis.